# How to grant rights to materialized view in Oracle11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, materialized-views

I'm very new to oracle and trying to grant rights to some materialized views I created.

What I've done (all from sqlplus command line):

> sqlplus "/ as sysdba

```
>create tablespace tablespace_test datafile 'g:\tables\tablespace_test.dbf' size 20M autoextend on;

>create materialized view test_mv_1 tablespace tablespace_test parallel build immediate refresh complete on demand as select cm.* from yyy.jjj$project@externaldb p, yyy.jjj$mgmt@externaldb cm where (p.project_nbr = cm.project_nbr);

>create user dummy profile default identified by password default tablespace tablespace_test account unlock;

>grant connect to dummy;

>grant select on test_mv_1 to dummy;

>select * from test_mv_1;   <---***this works, data is there

>connect dummy

>select * from test_mv_1;
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

Don't know how to fix this, and I'm sure I done some things wrong.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If the materialized view is owned by `SYS` (this is a **really** bad idea-- you should never, ever create objects in the `SYS` schema.  `SYS` is special.  It is reserved for Oracle.  It frequently behaves differently from every other schema in the database.) and there is no synonym created for the materialized view, you would need to specify the fully qualified name when you issued the query as `dummy`.  That is

```
SQL> connect dummy/password
SQL> select * from sys.test_mv_1;
```

You really, *really*, **really** want to create the materialized view in a different schema, though.  Assuming you create the materialized view in the `mv_owner` schema, the query would change to

```
select *
  from mv_owner.test_mv_1
```

If you want to avoid using a fully qualified name, you can create a synonym.  If you create a public synonym

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM test_mv_1
   FOR mv_owner.test_mv_1
```

or if you create a private synonym in the `dummy` schema

```
CREATE SYNONYM test_mv_1
   FOR mv_owner.test_mv_1
```

Then `dummy` would be able to specify an unqualified object name

```
SELECT *
  FROM test_mv_1
```

Comment: I know I need to do some reading up on Oracle.  I have a vague concept of schemas (similar to a profile, in the windows venacular, I think).  Is there some way to move the MVs to a different schema?